# How to set Values to Hyperlink filed from SharePoint desinger

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I am trying to set the values to hyperlink filed of document library from designer workflow.And below are the two implemented formats in designer workflow,But finding no luck

- {ULR}, {Description}
- url, description as (http://ulr/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/English-US/url/VMDLB/16CS385.xml&ClientInstalled=true&DefaultItemOpen=1, VMDLB)

And when I use the small url with description like https://www.linkedin.com, LinkedIn .It works for me ,But when I give my server url I getting the error as

**Error:**"The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information."

Can any one help me in sorting out this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the action **Set Field in Current Item**

in the  field, choose URL
in the value, use this format url, description

[image]

[image]

In your case

[image]

[image]